# Does RPC have a timeout mechanism?

Tags: go, rpc

If RPC does not have a timeout mechanism, how do I "kill" an RPC call if it is trying to call an RPC method of a server that is closed?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [channels](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#channels) to implement a timeout pattern:

```
import "time"

c := make(chan error, 1)
go func() { c <- client.Call("Service", args, &result) } ()
select {
  case err := <-c:
    // use err and result
  case <-time.After(timeoutNanoseconds):
    // call timed out
}
```

The `select` will block until either `client.Call` returns or `timeoutNanoseconds` elapsed.

Comment: This is a good solution. But be aware that, when timeout happens,  the goroutine will continue to run in the background, possibly holding on to OS resources.

Comment: This would be correct if it would be an unbuffered channel. As I'm using a buffered channel with size 1 the go routine will not block.

Comment: Sebastian, the goroutine may block forever in client.Call() if RPC server won't respond. This will result in goroutines' leak.

Comment: At least in Go 1.5, there is a client.Go method that is preferable

Comment: Please be aware that in a large scale service time.After results in memory issues since it won't get collected by GC until it's triggered. Instead of [time.Timer](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Timer) may be more desired because you can stop it manually.

Answer (score 4):

if you want to implement a timeout (to prevent a call from taking too long), then you'll want to change rpc.Dial for net.DialTimeout (notice they're separate packages: rpc vs net). Also be aware that the returned type isn't a client any more (as it is in the previous example); instead it is a 'connection'.

```
  conn, err := net.DialTimeout("tcp", "localhost:8080", time.Minute)
  if err != nil {
    log.Fatal("dialing:", err)
  }

  client := rpc.NewClient(conn)
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems the only solution for net/rpc is to close the underlying connection when you notice stuck requests. Then the client should finish pending requests with "connection broken" errors.

An alternative way is to use https://github.com/valyala/gorpc , which supports timeout RPC calls out of the box.

Comment: According my test, rpc.Client.Call method still not exit even I closed the underlying connection

Answer (score 1):

```
func (client *Client) Call(serviceMethod string, args interface{}, reply interface{}) error
```

Call method may block goroutine forever

Change use Go method:

```
func (client *Client) Go(serviceMethod string, args interface{}, reply interface{}, done chan *Call) *Call
```

Client example:

```
call := rpcClient.Go(method, args, reply, make(chan *rpc.Call, 1))
    select {
    case <-time.After(timeout):
        log.Printf("[WARN] rpc call timeout(%v) %v => %v", timeout, rpcClient, s.RpcServer)
        rpcClient.Close()
        return errors.New("timeout")
    case resp := <-call.Done:
        if resp != nil && resp.Error != nil {
            rpcClient.Close()
            return resp.Error
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Or, anno now, someone might prefer to use context instead. This also takes care of returning a proper error when timed out. (`context.DeadlineExceeded`)

```
import (
    "context"
    "log"
    "net/rpc"
)

type Client struct {
    *rpc.Client
}

// CallEx is a context aware wrapper around rpc's Client.Call()
func (c *client) CallEx(ctx context.Context, serviceMethod string, args interface{}, reply interface{}) error {
    ec := make(chan error, 1)
    go func() {
        ec <- c.Call(serviceMethod, args, reply)
    }()
    select {
    case err := <-ec:
        return err
    case <-ctx.Done():
        return ctx.Err()
    }
}
```

Invoke this with a Deadlined context:

```
type Args struct {
   A, B int
}

func main(){
    rpc, err := rpc.DialHTTP("tcp", "host")
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatal(err)
    }
    c := client{rpc}

    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 10*time.Second)
    defer cancel()

    var i int
    if err := c.CallEx(ctx, "Calc.Multiply", Args{2, 2}, &i); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

Comment: as upstairs @valyala 's comment remind,  
 if server not response, client.call will **never return**,
 the goroutine will **leak**.