# How to set SO_TIMEOUT for Go gRPC

Tags: sockets, go, timeout, grpc

I'm using gRPC with Go and needing to set the socket read timeout on the client connection (since the function available are all synchronous). Cannot seem to find anyway that I can set in the DialOption. Is there a way that I can set the timeout?

Also is there anyway that I can cancel a request?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does RPC have a timeout mechanism?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23330024/does-rpc-have-a-timeout-mechanism)

Comment: Have you tried go-cron library: https://github.com/jasonlvhit/gocron ? Itis not about a timeouts, yes, but maybe you can make a shedule like reading..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With no example code I can just give you a simple answer without a concrete example.

If you want to set a timeout you should use a context. The context interface provides a timeout which you can set inside the context: [godoc: Context](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/net/context#Context)

Inside the gRPC package you have the method for dial with a context: [godoc: DialContext](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/grpc#DialContext)

So just set the timeout inside your context and use the context when you dial.

Comment: You are welcome. If that answer helped you, I would be glad to get an upvote.

Comment: Say I made a successful Dial and am using the same connection object for making all subsequent grpc calls. Does even the grpc call timeout with this config or more config is required?